# remove/reset console.log in parcel.js

Tags: javascript, console.log, parceljs

When I **console.log** in my js files i cant track them , because  they all show up in the new js file created by parcel

when i try to console.log("test") in main.js file in line 3

result expected in console:
test ___  main.js.3

actual result in console :
test ___   main.9604d897.js.429

**parcel version** : 2.0.0-beta.1

**package.json:**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "parcel index.html"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. could you please try adding more details to your question? (ex. what you have tried, what resources you have used, more insight into your question, etc.) You might also find it beneficial to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: hi , thank u 
well i'm new to javascript , so i dont know what to try to fix that

i followed the Parcel ( getting starded ) documentation , and i watched some videos 
when they console.log something , the original js file is shown in the console 

but when i try to do so ,  the js file created by parcel is hown unstead of my original js path and line

Comment: what code editor are you using? (there's a possibility the code editor doesn't have a console)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-debug

Comment: thank u all for helping me , i figured out that problem was in the browser ( chrome ) the only solution i had its to swicth to Firefox

Answer (score 1):

After some test I figured out that the problem was in the browser,

I was using Chrome (Version 87.0.4280.88 (Build officiel) (64 bit))

when I tired using a different browser like Firefox , I had the normal output in the console

I will use Firefox as a default browser when working with parcel.